# Unable to run appium-doctor

Tags: node.js, macos, appium

I'm new to appium and during installation faced problem with appium-doctor.
While running `npm install appium-doctor -g` and `npm fund` it gave me the following output:

```
├── https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs
│   └── glob@7.2.3
├── https://github.com/sponsors/feross
│   └── safe-buffer@5.2.1, buffer@5.7.1, base64-js@1.5.1, ieee754@1.2.1
└── https://github.com/sponsors/epoberezkin
    └── ajv@6.12.6
```

and after I've run `appium-doctor` command it ended up like this:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './build/bin/appium-doctor'
Require stack:
- /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/appium-doctor.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/appium-doctor.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium-doctor/appium-doctor.js' ]
}
```

I've tried to reinstall both node and appium-doctor but it didn't helped.

M1 Monterey 12.5.1
| Homebrew 3.6.1
| node v16.17.0
| npm 8.19.1

Comment: How do you run the command

Comment: @mandaputtra simply from a current user, without sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try to install their newest version, your [current one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) is deprecated

```
npm install @appium/doctor -g
```